# Memory Storage for Notifications Service using SignalR

Tags: .net, push-notification, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm working on a .net 6.0 project using SignalR to send notifications to users.
I wanna store the notifications from users who were disconnected and re-send the notifications to these reconnected users. I'd like to use memory storage for all this. I can't find information and documentation about that.

This is my Hub:

```
  public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
     {
    
         private readonly IUserConnectionManager _userConnectionManager;
    
         public NotificationHub(IUserConnectionManager userConnectionManager)
         {
             _userConnectionManager = userConnectionManager;
         }
    
         private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _userConnections = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    
         public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
         {
             var token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["access_token"];
    
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
             {
                 bool successfulConnection = UserConnection(token);
                 if (successfulConnection)
                 {
                     var response = new ServerResponse
                     {
                         status = "Accepted",
                     };
                     await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).ConnectionResponse(response);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 var response = new ServerResponse
                 {
                     status = "Error",
                     message = "Token no proporcionado"
                 };
                 await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).ConnectionResponse(response);
                 Context.Abort();
             }
         }
    
         private bool UserConnection(string token)
         {
             var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
             var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
    
             if (jsonToken != null)
             {
                 string userId = jsonToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "email")?.Value;
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                 {
                     GetConnectionId(userId);
                 }
                 var response = new ServerResponse
                 {
                     status = "Accepted",
                 };
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
         }
    
         public string GetConnectionId(string userId)
         {
             _userConnectionManager.KeppUserConnection(userId, Context.ConnectionId);
             return Context.ConnectionId;
         }
    
         public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
         {
             var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
             _userConnectionManager.RemoveUserConnection(connectionId);
             await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
         }
    
         public async Task MessageCheck(NotificationRequestModel request)
         {
             //meter validaciones
             switch (request.Target.Device)
             {
                 case "Admin":
                     if (request.Target.User.Contains("*"))
                     {
                         SendNotificationToAllUsers(request.Notification);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         SendNotificationToSpecificUser(request.Notification, request.Target.User);
                     }
                     break;
             }
         }
    
         public async Task SendNotificationToAllUsers(NotificationModel message)
         {
             await Clients.All.SendNotificationToAllUsers(message);
         }
    
         public async Task SendNotificationToSpecificUser(NotificationModel message, List<string> target)
         {
             foreach (var userId in target)
             {
                 var connectionIds = _userConnectionManager.GetUserConnections(userId);
                 foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
                 {
                     await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendNotification(message);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Hi Eliass, You can take a look at the `GetUserIdFromToken` method I answered earlier, it looks like it's more than `jsonToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim. Type == "email")?. Value;'` more convenient.

Comment: Any way, glad hear you can fix the previous issue, and I hope the answer below could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this requirement by following code.

[image]

*InMemoryNotificationStore.cs*

```
using ASPNETCORE8.Models;

namespace ASPNETCORE8.IServices
{
    public class InMemoryNotificationStore : INotificationStore
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, List<NotificationModel>> _notifications = new();

        public void StoreNotification(string userId, NotificationModel notification)
        {
            if (!_notifications.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                _notifications[userId] = new List<NotificationModel>();
            }
            _notifications[userId].Add(notification);
        }

        public List<NotificationModel> RetrieveNotifications(string userId)
        {
            if (_notifications.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                return _notifications[userId];
            }
            return new List<NotificationModel>();
        }

        public void ClearNotifications(string userId)
        {
            if (_notifications.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                _notifications.Remove(userId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*INotificationStore.cs*

```
using ASPNETCORE8.Models;

namespace ASPNETCORE8.IServices
{
    public interface INotificationStore
    {
        void StoreNotification(string userId, NotificationModel notification);
        List<NotificationModel> RetrieveNotifications(string userId);
        void ClearNotifications(string userId);
    }

}
```

And this is my NotificationHub.cs

```
using ASPNETCORE8.IServices;
using ASPNETCORE8.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ASPNETCORE8.Hubs
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
    {
        private readonly IUserConnectionManager _userConnectionManager;
        private readonly INotificationStore _notificationStore;

        public NotificationHub(IUserConnectionManager userConnectionManager, INotificationStore notificationStore)
        {
            _userConnectionManager = userConnectionManager;
            _notificationStore = notificationStore;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["access_token"];
            // the logic of checking your token

            // checking the notifications once connected
            var userId = "testid";
            // get the messages from memory 
            var notifications = _notificationStore.RetrieveNotifications(userId);
            foreach (var notification in notifications)
            {
                await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendNotification(notification);
            }
            _notificationStore.ClearNotifications(userId);

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public async Task SendNotificationToSpecificUser(NotificationModel message, List<string> target)
        {
            foreach (var userId in target)
            {
                var connectionIds = _userConnectionManager.GetConnectionsByUserid(userId);
                // check the user is online or not
                if (connectionIds.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
                    {
                        await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendNotification(message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // if user is offline, then save the notification messages
                    _notificationStore.StoreNotification(userId, message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other files, INotificationHub.cs

```
using ASPNETCORE8.Models;

namespace ASPNETCORE8.IServices
{
    public interface INotificationHub
    {
        Task SendNotification(NotificationModel notification);
        Task ConnectionResponse(ServerResponse response);
    }

}
```

*IUserConnectionManager.cs*

```
namespace ASPNETCORE8.IServices
{
    public interface IUserConnectionManager
    {
        void AddConnection(string userId, string connectionId);
        void RemoveConnection(string userId, string connectionId);
        List<string> GetConnectionsByUserid(string userId);
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllConnections();
    }
}
```

*NotificationModel.cs*

```
namespace ASPNETCORE8.Models
{
    public class NotificationModel
    {
        public string? Title { get; set; } 
        public string? Message { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
                                          

        public NotificationModel()
        {
        }

        public NotificationModel(string title, string message, DateTime date)
        {
            Title = title;
            Message = message;
            Date = date;
        }

    }
}
```

*ServerResponse.cs*

```
namespace ASPNETCORE8.Models
{
    public class ServerResponse
    {
        public string? Status { get; set; } 
        public string? Message { get; set; } 
    }

}
```

*UserConnectionManager.cs*

```
using ASPNETCORE8.IServices;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace ASPNETCORE8.Services
{
    public class UserConnectionManager : IUserConnectionManager
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _connections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public void AddConnection(string userId, string connectionId)
        {
            _connections.AddOrUpdate(userId, new List<string> { connectionId }, (key, oldValue) =>
            {
                oldValue.Add(connectionId);
                return oldValue;
            });
        }

        public void RemoveConnection(string userId, string connectionId)
        {
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(userId, out var connections))
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);
                if (connections.Count == 0)
                {
                    _connections.TryRemove(userId, out _);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<string> GetConnectionsByUserid(string userId)
        {
            if (_connections.TryGetValue(userId, out var connections))
            {
                return connections;
            }
            return new List<string>();
        }
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllConnections()
        {
            return _connections.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

And the settings in Program.cs.

```
...
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<INotificationStore, InMemoryNotificationStore>()
...
var app = builder.Build();
```